# Наречие или прилагательное

Tags: морфология, части-речи

Не могу определить, какой частью речи (наречие или прилагательное) являются слова *больше, умнее, меньше* в предложениях: 1) Больше науки — умнее руки;   2) Больше дела — меньше слов. Почему? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Больше` являются омонимами: совпадающими простыми сравнительными формами прилагательного `большой` и наречия `много`.

`Умнее` являются омонимами: совпадающими простыми сравнительными формами прилагательного `умный` и наречия `умно`.

`Меньше` являются омонимами: совпадающими простыми сравнительными формами прилагательных `малый`, `маленький`, и наречия `мало`.

Чтобы понять чем именно является конкретное слово, необходимо определить какое именно значение оно имеет в контексте. Можно, например, попробовать трансформировать фразу и вернуть начальную форму слова.

`Больше` в обоих примерах используется в смысле "сейчас мало, а нужно чтобы было много" или "нужно, чтобы было *более* много чем сейчас". Делаем вывод, что `Больше`—сравнительная степень наречия `много`.

Обратите внимание, что восстановить тут прилагательное `большой` не получается. Что-то большее по размеру/важности чем наука? Или дело *более* большое чем что-то? Эти вопросы не подходят к смыслу фраз.

`Умнее` используется в значении "стать более умным". Фразу можно развернуть в: "Чем больше науки, тем более умными становятся руки". То есть, `умнее` является сравнительной степенью прилагательного `умный`.

Восстановить тут наречие тоже никак не получается. Сравните ваш пример с примером, в котором используется наречие: "Я пошутил умно, но он пошутил умнее".

`Меньше` употребляется в значении "сейчас слишком много, а нужно чтобы было мало" или "нужно, чтобы было *более* мало (*менее* много) чем сейчас". `Меньше`—это сравнительная степень наречия `мало`.

Заметьте, как изменится смысл, если мы подставим `меньше` вместо `умнее` в ваш первый пример: `Больше науки — меньше руки`. Смысл "сейчас слишком много, а нужно чтобы было мало" тут уже не применим—тут `меньше` используется в значении "руки были нормального размера, а станут маленькими".

Answer (score 3):

***Больше науки — умнее руки.  Больше дела — меньше слов.***

Итак, перед нами, очевидно, пословицы в форме бессоюзных сложных предложений.

При наличии союзов это выглядело бы так:

Чем больше науки, тем умнее руки.

Чем больше дела, тем меньше слов. Или: Лучше больше дела, да меньше слов.

1. *Много науки, много дела, мало слов* – это числовые обороты, наречия *много* и  *мало* употреблены  в значении **неопределенного количественного числительного.**

Сравнительная степень: ***больше, меньше***.  Много науки – больше науки, много дела – больше дела, мало слов – меньше слов.

Прилагательные *маленький* и *большой* также имеют сравнительную степень *больше* и *меньше*, но здесь нет такого значения (большой, маленький).

*Умный – умнее* – это сравнительная степень **прилагательного.** Руки умные, руки умнее.

**2. Вывод.** В данных предложениях ***больше*** и ***меньше*** – это сравнительная степень **наречий** (неопределенных количественных **числительных**).

***Умнее*** – сравнительная степень прилагательного.